# Training a deformable-part-based-model classifer on my own data to recognize different vehicles

Tags: computer-vision, classification, image-recognition, object-detection, haar-classifier

For comparison purposes with a multiclass-classification system, I need to use the Deformable part-based model [here](https://github.com/rbgirshick/voc-dpm) to train a classifier to detect different types of vehicles. (Cars, trucks and buses in this case).

And if possible, to be able to distinguish the angle as well (frontal view, side view, etc).

So I need to use my own training and testing data.

- Ideally, I'd like the system to be able to distinguish from one type of vehicle to another. (i.e. this is a car versus a bus).
- But if that's not possible, then at least I want it to be able to recognize that a bus is a vehicle, as is a car or a truck, given different viewpoints.

I understand we have to put our training and testing images in a folders names VOCdevkit, etc. But my question is about the different classes. How can I train the system to recognize different types of vehicles?

How do I go about this? Do I simply put all images with their different class labels in the same folder? Or do I train individual classifiers?